# xpath parent and descendants in scrapy

Tags: xml, xpath, scrapy, parent, descendant

I am using code

```
response.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Role')]/parent/parent/descendant::td//text()").extract()
```

to select all td text() content from rows following where word 'Role' is found in the following html table:

```
<table class="wh_preview_detail" border="1">
   <tr>
      <th colspan="3">
         <span class="wh_preview_detail_heading">Names</span>
      </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>Role</th>
      <th>Name No</th>
      <th>Name</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Requestor</td>
      <td>589528</td>
      <td>John</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Helper</td>
      <td>589528</td>
      <td>Mary</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The 'Role' keyword is only acting as an identifier for the table.

In this case I'm expecting results:

```
['Requestor', '589528', 'John', ...]
```

However, I get an empty array when performing in scrapy.

My aim is to ultimately group the elements again as records.
I have spent a few hours trying others' examples and experimenting in terminal and Chrome but all but 'simple' XPath is beyond me right now.
I am looking to understand Xpath so ideally would like a generalised answer with explanation, that way I can learn and also share. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As general advice, it's usually easier to craft your XPath expression by going down the tree, step by step, instead of selecting `//typeiwant` all the way down, and adding predicates for what came before in the tree (with parent or ancestor)

Let's look at how to solve your use case with Scrapy selectors:

```
>>> import scrapy
>>> t = '''<table class="wh_preview_detail" border="1">
...    <tr>
...       <th colspan="3">
...          <span class="wh_preview_detail_heading">Names</span>
...       </th>
...    </tr>
...    <tr>
...       <th>Role</th>
...       <th>Name No</th>
...       <th>Name</th>
...    </tr>
...    <tr>
...       <td>Requestor</td>
...       <td>589528</td>
...       <td>John</td>
...    </tr>
...    <tr>
...       <td>Helper</td>
...       <td>589528</td>
...       <td>Mary</td>
...    </tr>
... </table>'''
>>> selector = scrapy.Selector(text=t, type="html")
>>>
>>> # what you want comes inside a <table>,
>>> # after a <tr> that has a child `<th>` with text "Role" inside
>>> selector.xpath('//table/tr[th[1]="Role"]')
[<Selector xpath='//table/tr[th[1]="Role"]' data=u'<tr>\n      <th>Role</th>\n      <th>Name '>]
>>>
>>> # check with .extract() is that's the one...
>>> selector.xpath('//table/tr[th[1]="Role"]').extract()
[u'<tr>\n      <th>Role</th>\n      <th>Name No</th>\n      <th>Name</th>\n   </tr>']
>>>
```

Then, the rows you're interested in are at the same tree level as that `<tr>` with "Role". In XPath terms, these `<tr>` elements are along the `following-sibling` axis

```
>>> for row in selector.xpath('//table/tr[th[1]="Role"]/following-sibling::tr'):
...     print('------')
...     print(row.extract())
... 
------
<tr>
      <td>Requestor</td>
      <td>589528</td>
      <td>John</td>
   </tr>
------
<tr>
      <td>Helper</td>
      <td>589528</td>
      <td>Mary</td>
   </tr>
>>>
```

So you have each row, each row having 3 cells, to map to 3 fields:

```
>>> for row in selector.xpath('//table/tr[th[1]="Role"]/following-sibling::tr'):
...     print({
...         "role": row.xpath('normalize-space(./td[1])').extract_first(),
...         "number": row.xpath('normalize-space(./td[2])').extract_first(),
...         "name": row.xpath('normalize-space(./td[3])').extract_first(),
...     })
... 
{'role': u'Requestor', 'number': u'589528', 'name': u'John'}
{'role': u'Helper', 'number': u'589528', 'name': u'Mary'}
>>>
```